# Laravel Queue - Database in cache?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-sqs, laravel-queue

1. I have an application with multiple databases;
2. I have a function to "choose" the correct database;

The problem is: when I start `php artisan queue:work --tries=3`

The project join in `MySqlConnector.php` only in first time.
So, I just can connect in my correct database in the first time.

#### Attempts fails

1. Disconnect `\DB::disconnect('database name')`,
2. Clear cache `\Cache::flush();`
3. Change the mysql default `config(['database.connections.queue' => $correctDatabase]);`

And several others I don't even remember anymore.

**How do I make sure that whenever I enter a queue worker, I will connect back to the database?**

> Note: I enter the correct database configuration inside MySQLConnector in the connect method.

```php
public function connect(array $config)
{
     // ...
        // multipleDatabases is my custom function 
        if(multipleDatabases('connection') !== null) {
            $config = multipleDatabases('database');
        }
    // ...
}
```

This code working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem using `listen` instead of `worker`

```php
php artisan queue:listen --tries=3
```

[Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#running-the-queue-worker)

> When using the queue:listen command, you don't have to manually restart the worker after your code is changed; however, this command is not as efficient as queue:work:

Comment: bear in mind that this will increase the CPU usage.

Comment: @GuillermoMansilla Unfortunately will increase, but  do you know how can I clear only the database information in queue completion?